# Truncate Oracle table using Spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

my first question here!

I’m learning Spark and so far is awesome. Now I’m writing some DFs to Oracle using `DF.write.mode(“append”).jdbc`

Now, I need to truncate the table since I don’t want to append.  If I use “overwrite” mode, it will drop the table and create a new one but I’ll will have to reGRANT users to Get access to it. Not good.

Can I do something like truncate in Oracle using spark SQL? Open for suggestions! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option to make Spark to truncate target Oracle table instead of dropping it. You can find the syntax https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14086

```
spark.range(10).write.mode("overwrite").option("truncate", true).jdbc(url, "table_with_index", prop)
```

Depending on the versions of Spark, Oracle and JDBC driver, there are other parameters that you could use to make the truncate on cascade as you can see from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

From my experience, that works on some of DB engines, and depends a lot on the JDBC that you use, because not all of them support it

Hope this helps